# Java swingworker processing an ArrayList on regular intervals

Tags: java, swingworker

I have a SwingWorker processing a list of Strings `ArrayList<String>` from a db on a regular interval to update the GUI with latest data.  I have the `doInBackground()` method running in a continuous loop (that sleeps after each interval).

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    while (true) {
        ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>(db.getList(true));
        Collections.sort(list);

        publish(list);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }       
}
```

On each interval, I call publish so my caller can get the updated list, which I pass to my caller via a target object like so:

```
@Override
protected void process(List<ArrayList<String>> list) {
    ArrayList<String> s = list.get(list.size() - 1);
    target.statusUpdate(s);
    super.process(list);        
}
```

I'm worried that if the list is long, it seems that my List of Lists could get memory intensive.  I only care about the current list, not the history of all the lists pulled.  It makes me think I've set this up incorrectly.

How can I optimize this?

Comment: You could ... remove the processed elements out of the list. Note that Java provides classes that represent queues.

Comment: But SwingWorker is what defined the List..

Comment: If you're concerned about concurrency issues, good. There are multiple ways to handle this. One is [ConcurrentLinkedDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html).

Comment: I am overriding a method signature that is defined by SwingWorker, so how can I use this class to solve the problem of the List becoming long?  I'm not concerned about my ArrayList (which is fairly static), I'm concerned about the List.  My understanding is List keeps growing with each iteration of process() being called?

Comment: After some more reading on this, I realized we are using SwingWorker incorrectly.  I changed to a Timer that calls the functionality I need, which eliminates the problem described above.